# SQL query showing partial data

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

When combining multiple tables I am getting results but they are only partial results. I know the issues is most likely my joins or lack of joins, I just don't seem to be able to get them correct (I'm not a SQL Dev, just thrown this issue to "figure" it out)

I am basically wanting to combine both of these tables. Here are my tables / queries, These queries are the basic select statements for each table I am trying to get data from.

**Table one**

```
select LB.WBS1, LB.WBS2, LB.LaborCode, LB.AmtBud, LB.HrsBud
from lB 
where wbs1 = '10312-00'
```

Results

[LB Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVdy.png)

Here you can see laborcode 02,03,04,06,13

This table is the Labor Budget, which gives me the first half of my report. The second table is the Labor Detail which includes hours put against an actual project. I need to combine both of this into one SQL statement so that I can use in to create an SSRS report.

**Table Two**

```
Select LD.WBS1, LD.WBS2, ld.laborcode, ld.regamt, ld.reghrs
from LD
Where ld.wbs1 = '10312-00'
group by ld.laborcode, ld.regamt, ld.reghrs
```

Results

[LD Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A751v.png)

Here you can see laborcode 01 (which is what I'm missing)

The query I have been using combing both tables

```
SELECT  
    dbo.CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS.label,
    dbo.LB.hrsbud,
    dbo.LB.rate,
    dbo.LB.amtbud,
    dbo.LD.reghrs,
    dbo.LD.ovthrs,
    dbo.LD.regamt,
    dbo.LD.reghrs + dbo.LD.ovthrs AS JTD,
    dbo.LB.laborcode,
    dbo.PR.wbs1,
    dbo.PR.wbs2,
    dbo.PR.pctcomp,
    dbo.PR.exppctcomp
FROM   
    dbo.CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LB ON dbo.CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS.code = dbo.LB.laborcode
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PR ON dbo.LB.wbs1 = dbo.PR.wbs1 AND dbo.LB.wbs2 = dbo.PR.wbs2
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.LD ON dbo.PR.wbs1 = dbo.LD.wbs1 AND dbo.PR.wbs2 = dbo.LD.wbs2
WHERE  
    (dbo.LB.wbs1 = '10312-00')
ORDER BY 
    dbo.LB.laborcode,dbo.LD.laborcode
```

[Results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r7qd.png)

This query returns a large data set of 154 rows. This picture is only the first page, then the data repeats itself with a new labor code of 03, repeats 04, 06, 13. The problem is there is not a labor code of 01. I might be using the wrong table to start with.

This is what I am trying to come up with, more or less:
[Final Result Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSHCl.png)
The problem is that Laborcode=01 only appears in LD table. Basically my report consists of LB (laborBudget) table which is the left half of the report, and the LD (laborDetail) table which is the right half. This is for a gain/loss report ive been asked to custom build in SSRS, after I can get the right data pulled.

This is a hard question to ask because I'm not sure what to ask, as I am not a SQL person.

Comment: seems like it might have something to do with the values of wbs2.  Can you redo the top two queries with the wbs1 and wbs2 fields in the result set?  Then we could confirm...

Comment: I have made the changes so you can see wbs1 and wbs2 in the top two queries.

Comment: Ok.  There is no laborcode = 01 in the LB data set, yet you are joining to that table using the join clause of ON dbo.CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS.code = dbo.LB.laborcode.

Comment: In your final, combined results set of both tables -- are you wanting a unique row/result ForEach laborCode? Or is multiple rows for a given laborCode okay for what you want?

Comment: How would you like to handle if LB dataset does not have the laborcode?  Or should it just be inserted?

Comment: @RoboBear yes a unique row for each labor code, well there would be two of the same labor codes but different WBS2 codes. I.E. WBS2 A laborCode 02,04,06,13 etc, WBS2 B LaborCode 02,04,06,13.

Comment: @ElementZero Inserted I'm guessing because of the way the final report looks. If it helps I'm building the final version in SSRS.

Comment: I don't think you can get that final report like you want because you want JTD and that would not be available since the where clause relies on LB.  How would you join to LD? otherwise check my query below...

Comment: I can get JTD later just using expressions in SSRS, I was doing it in the SQL statement to make it quicker if that's a big deal. I see what you mean about the where clause relying on LB. This has been my issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a question: What about instead of trying to join these tables which are causing so much of an issue, I go a different direction. This report is only ran when a user requests is and the report is based off of WBS1 or the "project Number". When SSRS runs the built in report its gnarly some 3500 lines of SQL, but it starts by building a temp table to work from. What if I did something similar and built a temp table and inserted data into it from the different sources I need and only had to reference that one report to pull my information, and at the end it dropped from the database? Is this something that is possible? I'm willing to do the research and figure it out I just don't want to follow the white rabbit and waste time.

Comment: If I'm understanding you want implementation ideas for temporary tables "scoped"to the running of one report. One idea -- for SQL Server specifically -- is to use a CTE Query. 

Example/Source -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

Comment: That link is broken, leads to a page that is not found.

Answer (score 0):

As I said before, laborcode = 01 doesn't exist in LB recordset.  You can change your query to the one below that will basically give you the 01 but the rest null because LB doesn't exist for that record

```
SELECT    d.code as laborcode,
          d.label,
          q.hrsbud,
          q.rate,
          q.amtbud,
          q.reghrs,
          q.ovthrs,
          q.regamt,
          q.JTD,
          q.wbs1,
          q.wbs2,
          q.pctcomp,
          q.exppctcomp
FROM dbo.CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select    lb.laborcode,
              lb.hrsbud,
              lb.rate,
              lb.amtbud,
              ld.reghrs,
              ld.ovthrs,
              ld.regamt,
              ld.reghrs + ld.ovthrs AS JTD,
              pr.wbs1,
              pr.wbs2,
              pr.pctcomp,
              pr.exppctcomp
    from dbo.LB lb
    INNER JOIN dbo.PR pr
        ON lb.wbs1 = pr.wbs1 AND lb.wbs2 = pr.wbs2
    INNER JOIN dbo.LD ld
        ON ld.wbs1 = pr.wbs1 AND ld.wbs2 = pr.wbs2
    WHERE (lb.wbs1 = '10312-00')
)q on (d.code = q.laborcode)
ORDER BY d.code
```

example with '00' removed and grouping the wbs then summing hours together

```
SELECT    d.code as laborcode,
          d.label,
          SUM(q.hrsbud) as hrsbud,
          SUM(q.rate) as rate,
          SUM(q.amtbud) as amtbud,
          SUM(q.reghrs) as reghrs,
          SUM(q.ovthrs) as ovthrs,
          SUM(q.regamt) as regamt,
          SUM(q.JTD) as JTD,
          MIN(q.wbs1) as wbs1,
          MIN(q.wbs2) as wbs2,
          SUM(q.pctcomp) as pctcomp,
          SUM(q.exppctcomp) as exppctcomp
FROM dbo.CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select    lb.laborcode,
              lb.hrsbud,
              lb.rate,
              lb.amtbud,
              ld.reghrs,
              ld.ovthrs,
              ld.regamt,
              ld.reghrs + ld.ovthrs AS JTD,
              pr.wbs1,
              pr.wbs2,
              pr.pctcomp,
              pr.exppctcomp
    from dbo.LB lb
    INNER JOIN dbo.PR pr
        ON lb.wbs1 = pr.wbs1 AND lb.wbs2 = pr.wbs2
    INNER JOIN dbo.LD ld
        ON ld.wbs1 = pr.wbs1 AND ld.wbs2 = pr.wbs2
    WHERE (lb.wbs1 = '10312-00')
)q on (d.code = q.laborcode)
where d.code <> '00'
group by d.code, d.label
ORDER BY d.code
```

Comment: When i run this code I get a syntax error line 16 near 'Select' and like 34 near ')'

Comment: sorry, typo - try now

Comment: The query runs now, just pulls duplicates and a laborcode that isnt in either LD or LB, '00'. I'm going back to the drawing board in a view and see if I can't get closer. Thanks

Comment: The 00 would come from your CFGLCCODESDESCRIPTIONS table, you could get rid of that by adding a where d.code <> '00'.  The dupes are caused by duplicate records in your LD table for the same wbs1 and wbs2 - you need to group the records and do something like SUM the fields together or something - your example output doesn't state how you want this to happen.

Comment: I see what your talking about now, I just need to clean it up and I should be able to use this. If not use at least model after it, Thanks.